# File uploader is not working and no files are moved to the designated folder.

Tags: php, file-upload, directory

I am creating an item form where the admin can add items to stock along with their images. I want to save the images as "$item_id.jpg" in a "img/items" folder. Unfortunately my items get added to the database but the file does not get uploaded to the designated folder. Below is my code your help will be much appreciated.

```
//Code for the form----------------------------------------------
<form class="stock" method="post" action="">
<table class="newstocktable">
    <tr>
        <th>Size:</th>
        <td> 
            <select name= "size">
            <option> </option>
            <?php
                require ('connection.php');
                $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM fyp_size")or die(mysql_error());
                while($result = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
                    echo '<option>'.$result['size'].'</option>';
                }
            ?>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Item name:</th>
        <td> 
            <input type="text" name="name" id="Name"  <?php if (isset($_POST['name'])=== true){echo 'value="', strip_tags($_POST['name']),'"';}?>>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Description: </th>
        <td> 
            <textarea name="desc" <?php if (isset($_POST['desc'])=== true){echo 'value="', strip_tags($_POST['desc']),'"';}?>></textarea>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Price (£): </th>
        <td> 
            <input type="text" name="price" <?php if (isset($_POST['price'])=== true){echo 'value="', strip_tags($_POST['price']),'"';}?>>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Quantity: </th>
        <td> 
            <input type="text" name="quantity" <?php if (isset($_POST['quantity'])=== true){echo 'value="', strip_tags($_POST['quantity']),'"';}?>>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Threshold: </th>
        <td> 
            <input type="text" name="threshold" <?php if (isset($_POST['threshold'])=== true){echo 'value="', strip_tags($_POST['threshold']),'"';}?>>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Product image:</th>
        <td>
            <input type="file" name="item_img" id="item_img">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="submit" name="addnewstock" value= "Add Stock">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

```
//PHP parsing code-------------------------------------
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM items WHERE name='$name' && 
size_id='$sizeid'")or die(mysql_error());
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
if($numrows == 0){
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO items VALUES(
    '', '$sizeid', '$name', '$desc', '$price', '$quantity', '$threshold', now()
    )")or die(mysql_error());
    $item_id = mysql_insert_id();
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM items WHERE name='$name'")or die(mysql_error());
    $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
    if ($numrows == 1){
        $errors[] = 'Item was added.';
        $filename = "$item_id.jpg";
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['item_img']['temp_name'], "img/items/$filename");
        mysql_close();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try giving the form an enctype attribute with a value of multipart/form-data.

Comment: Thanks for your help, It still doesnt upload even with the form header changed to:
<form class="stock" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="">

Comment: In your php parsing code, change $filename to $filename = $item_id . ".jpg". You have it set to "$item_id.jpg" which is wrong because you can't append variables to an string within doible quotes. You have to concatenate it using .

Comment: Thanks for your advice but I still can't get it working :( this is now my code...
$filename = $item_id.".jpg";
              move_uploaded_file($_FILES['item_img']['temp_name'], "img/items/$filename");
              mysql_close();

Comment: Try: move_uploaded_file($_FILES['item_img']['temp_name'], "img/items/" . $filename);

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your form you are missing `enctype=”multipart/form-data”>`

```
<form class="stock" method="post" action="" enctype=”multipart/form-data”>
```

This is required if you want to add any `<input type="file">` and handle the uploaded file in the `$_FILE` array

Comment: I tried it, but it still doesn't upload the image :(. Everything parses fine. I don't get errors, warnings or notices so I don't know what is going wrong. Below is the form header:
<form class="stock" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="">

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with my "move_uploaded_file" code the store location to be precise. Before my code was:

```
"img/items/$filename"
```

It did not assign a filed name and therefore the file was not uploaded. however this fixed it...

```
"img/items/".$filename
```

The key was to append the $filename variable rather than including it as a string. Thanks to user3316397 for pointing it out :)